# On clicking capture hyperlink in string and do not open the browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink

This div is in a [radRotator](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/rotator/examples/livexml/defaultcs.aspx) control and generate a clickable link that, on click, opens the url in a new page of the browser.

```
<div class="link">
 <span><a href="<%#XPath("link").ToString()%>" target="_blank">Link</a></span>
</div>
```

*I am looking for a method to capture the link value in a string when it is clicked and avoid to open the browser.*

My final target is to pass such string to a method that will open the url in a window where I can filter out all the parts I do not like to show to avoid the user to leave the website and visit the one linked. I am a bit lost on this.  Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an "onclick" event to your link, capture the `href` attribute and cancel the default click action by returning `false`.

E.g. (for simplicity I am using inline declaration)

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" onclick="alert(this.href);return false">Link</a>
```

To expand on your example, you can do something like this:

**ASPX**

```
<a href="<%#XPath("link").ToString()%>" target="_blank" onclick="return getLink(this);">
```

**JavaScript**

```
function getLink(anch) {
    var sLink = anch.href; // you can use this variable, it will hold the link now

    // rest of your code

    return false;
}
```

Comment: That looks brilliant! Thanks. Could you point me on how to call a java script and pass such variable from there?

Comment: Updated my answer with an example